# Class Variable Syntax error

Tags: java

I am learning scope and nested classes. I created a nested class and created the int money variable at class level; however, when I try to redefine the variable in the nested class, it sends this error
Syntax error on token "money", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

```
 package taopablot;

public class Scope {
private int money = 5;

class mySecondDragon {
    money=5;
    public void mySecondDragon()
    {
        System.out.println(money);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The variable money does not a property of the inner class so u can't modify its value out side  a method

Answer (score 0):

```
class mySecondDragon {
    money=5;  // #2
    public void mySecondDragon()
    {
        System.out.println(money);
    }
};
```

Look the line no 2. You have to hide the top level classes money variable which is fine but it's missing a type. Probably

```
int money =5;
```

If you don't want to hide and just want to assign some value to top level classes variable, that should not the way. That statement either in constructor, method or any other block. In current state that's a kind of orphaned statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to set a field within the class block but outside of methods, like you are doing for money in the inner class, then you can use an **initialization block**:

```
{ money = 5; }
```

But if you are trying to redefine the field money in your inner class, then you need to declare it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create a set and get method for money.

```
void setMoney(int amount){
money = amount;
}
void getMoney(){
return money;
}
```

your updated code would look like this:

```
public class Scope {
private int money = 5;

void setMoney(int amount){
money = amount;
}

void getMoney(){
return money;
}

class mySecondDragon {
Scope.setMoney(5);
public void mySecondDragon()
{
    System.out.println(Scope.getMoney());
}
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Scope {
    private int money = 0;

    class mySecondDragon {

        void mySecondDragon() {
            money = 5;
            System.out.println(money);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scope st = new Scope();
        Scope.mySecondDragon fl = st.new mySecondDragon();
        fl.mySecondDragon();
    }

}
```